# Searching in python dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, search, iteration

I have a dictionary of dictionary called `data_dict`. Following is how it looks:

```
{'UMANOFF ADAM S': {'total_stock_value': 'NaN', 'loans': 'NaN', 'salary': 288589},
'YEAP SOON': {'total_stock_value': 192758, 'loans': 'NaN', 'salary': 'NaN'},
'PIPER GREGORY F': {'total_stock_value': 880290, 'loans': 1452356, 'salary': 19791},
'Jack S': {'total_stock_value': 88000, 'loans': 'NaN', 'salary': 288589}
}
```

Basically it is of the format

```
{Person Name : Dictionary of that person's attributes}
```

I am trying to find the name of a person whose salary is certain X. 
Specifically in above example - let's say I am trying to find the name of the persons whose salary is 288589. I expect all the names whose salary is 288589.

I have written following generalised function which will take a search key and value and return names of the persons for which that key, value holds true.

```
def search_person_by_attribute(attribute, value):
    person_names = []

    for person, attributes_dict in data_dict.items():
        if attributes_dict[attribute] == value:
            person_names.append(person)

    return person_names
```

This method runs successfully

```
results = search_person_by_attribute("salary", 288589)
print(results)
```

and prints

```
['UMANOFF ADAM S','Jack S']
```

But somehow I feel this is quite a long way write it. Is there a better/shorter/more pythonic way to do it?

If you can also mention the efficiency (in terms of time complexity) of my as well your suggested solution will be a great bonus.

Comment: you could create a specialized dictionary for your needs, using the current dictionary as input.

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, why not create a new dictionary in the format `{salary: (name1, name2)}` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre & Chris_Rands not really. I have used salary as an example in the question. The dataset is huge and I need to search variety of attributes and not just salary. The creating a new dictionary won't be a good idea here. :-)

Comment: @PaleBlueDot that's just a compromise between performance and memory

Comment: @PaleBlueDot If the data set is huge, using a real database might be better in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre precisely :-)

Comment: @L3viathan the dataset is huge but not that huge to demand a real database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest something like this, which I think is not just shorter, but more readable than your version:

```
def search_person_by_attribute(d, attribute, value):
    return [name for name in d if d[name][attribute] == value]
```

It works exactly like yours, but requires the dictionary as an additional parameter, because I think that's better style:

```
>>> search_person_by_attribute(d, "salary", 288589)
['UMANOFF ADAM S', 'Jack S']
```

Comment: @Chris It's just O(number_of_people), since dictionary access is O(1), but yes, still linear.

Comment: This definitely looks better. Although I will wait for a while before accepting it as the best answer. Also I doubt that efficiency/time complexity wise any of the solutions to such a search will ever be better than O(number_of_people).

Comment: @PaleBlueDot They can be if you do all the searching before, i.e. if you make a reversed dictionary, so you can just do `reversed_dict["salary"][288589]`, then it'd be O(1), but you'll need about twice the space in memory, if you also want to keep the original dictionary.